# Unknown variable being moved into EAX register

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

For the following function:

```
void say_hello (void) { 

    char name[5]; 
    gets(name); //this is a unsafe function to use. Results in stack overflow
    printf("Hello %s\n", name); 

}
```

[image: Say hello function]

I know that `rbp+var_5` is the argument for the `gets()` function and `rbp+var_10` is the argument for the `printf` function. But what is `rbp+var_14`? and why is it being moved into the EAX register?

Comment: The comment to the C-code is wrong. `gets()` may result in *buffer overflow*, which is a different (more severe) problem than *stack overflow*.

Comment: @EOF couldn't this cause both stack and buffer overflow?

Comment: Well, buffer overflow is undefined behaviour, so as far as C is concerned literally *anything* could happen. But *practically*, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read it backwards. This assembly language code is in Intel syntax, which looks like `instruction  destination, source`.

The line `mov  dword [ss:rbp:var+14], eax` copies `eax`, which contains the return value from calling `printf()`, into a temporary variable on the stack. Then the variable is thrown away (no code afterwards reads from it).